# Access to main dialog variables within thread (MFC)

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, mfc

I have a GUI application with MFC. I'am lauching thread to process some data using AfxBeginThread(). And i've got problem accessing to main dialog in thread:

Through this struct I'am passing main dialog handler and pointer to main dlg object to thread. But at strcpy() line debugger stops and shows   **pDlg->0x430f0020 {CTabDlg hWnd=???}**

```
typedef struct {
    LPVOID myHandle;
    LPVOID myPointer;
} sParamData;


UINT WorkerThreadProc_type2( LPVOID Param )
{


    UpdInfo info;   
    sParamData *s;

    s = (sParamData*)Param;
    HWND hMainHandle = (HWND) (*s).myHandle;
    CtabDlg* pDlg = (CtabDlg*)(*s).myPointer;

    strcpy(apikey, pDlg->m_sVar);
...
}
```

I tried both XP and Windows 7 OS. In XP it always crashes, but in Seven it works. This is how i pass the struct to the thread:

```
sParamData s;
    s.myHandle = (HWND)GetSafeHwnd();
    s.myPointer = (CtabDlg*) this;

    if(CurrTab == 1)
    {
        AfxBeginThread(WorkerThreadProc_type2, &s, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,0,0,NULL);
        pPage2->GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON1)->EnableWindow(FALSE);
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Some remarks that have nothing to do with the program crashing: `sParamData` should not contain `LPVOID` types but the actual types, that is `HWND` and `CtabDlg`. This will avoid all casts to and from these types. Furthermore write `s->myHandle` instead of `(*s).myHandle`, it's equivalent but no C programmer writes `(*s).` instead of `s->`.

Comment: It could be a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), that is at some point `CTabDlg` doesn't exist anymore, but your thread is not aware of this.

Comment: @ Michael Walz, CTabDlg is a main dialog and exists all the time, also it always works in windows seven somehow.

Comment: OK, but there may very well be cases where the race condifion leads to a problem on one platform but not on another, BTW: where did you declare `sParamData *s` ?

Comment: @ Michael Walz, thanks you probably right. I declared sParamData *s in button hanlder right before starting thread in the code. And now i put declaration to the main class and filled the structure at OnInitdialog(). It works fine, but still can't understand why it caused race condition, while s structure was filled BEFORE lauchind thread =\

Comment: On W7 the thread seems start a bit earlier so the variable `s` still exists when you read it from the thread, where as on XP the the thread seems to start a bit later and `s` doesn't exist any more when the thread tries to read it. A typical case of race condition.

Comment: Have you considerred adjusting the code so that the application is exposed as global? Then you can use theApp. Or instead AfxGetApp or AfxGetMainWnd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code is exactly as your real case then here you are declaring a local sParamData and passing its address to thread. This gives a race condition: s can go out of scope before the thread start execution, (or reaches the point where its content is copied).

```
sParamData s;
s.myHandle = (HWND)GetSafeHwnd();
s.myPointer = (CtabDlg*) this;

if(CurrTab == 1)
{
    AfxBeginThread(WorkerThreadProc_type2, &s, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,0,0,NULL);
    pPage2->GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON1)->EnableWindow(FALSE);
```

The simplest workaround is probably allocate s on heap and delete it in thread after its content has been copied.

Like this:

```
sParamData *s = new sParamData ;
s->myHandle = (HWND)GetSafeHwnd();
s->myPointer = (CtabDlg*) this;

if(CurrTab == 1)
{
    AfxBeginThread(WorkerThreadProc_type2, s, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,0,0,NULL);
    pPage2->GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON1)->EnableWindow(FALSE);
```

And then, inside the thread

```
UINT WorkerThreadProc_type2( LPVOID Param )
{
    UpdInfo info;   
    sParamData *s = (sParamData*)Param;
    HWND hMainHandle = (HWND) s->myHandle;
    CtabDlg* pDlg = (CtabDlg*)s->.myPointer;
    // assuming s will no longer be used you can delete it here
    delete s ;
```

Comment: I declared sParamData s in main dlg class and initialized it in OnInitDialog(), now it works fine, but can you show me example of code that will do it in "right way it should be done, please.